# Checking if a path matches any regex without going through the complete list

Tags: haskell

Hello am trying to match regular expressions with a `FilePath` to filter my list of files

```
import Text.Regex.Posix
import System.FilePath

escapePath path = foldr (&&) True $ map (\pat -> not $  (path =~ pat :: Bool)) patterns
                   where
                       patterns = ["\\.",  "\\.\\.", {-- So on --}]
```

I believe `map` and `folds` would traverse over the complete list before returning a value.

I could avoid using fold by doing something like this

```
escapePath path = not $ elem True (map (\pat -> (path =~ pat :: Bool)) patterns)
                    where
                       patterns = ["\\.",  "\\.\\.", {-- continued --}]
```

But still I would be matching the path against all patterns before searching for a value

How can I make the function more efficient by returning a value on first match?

Comment: Your assumption about map and foldr is incorrect. Try `foldr (&&) True (map not [True, undefined])`. In other words, it already has the behavior you want. See also the Prelude function `all` instead of your map and foldr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I believe `map` and `fold`s would traverse over the complete list before returning a value.

Hey, great, a falsifiable hypothesis, the cornerstone of science! Let's do an experiment to attempt to falsify it. For any value `foo`, traversing the list `foo:undefined` completely will throw an exception.

```
> head (map id (True:undefined))
True
> foldr (&&) True (False:undefined)
False
```

[image]